# How to extract SQLite file from Android SD card

Tags: android, sqlite

My Galaxy S was having an error on the notification bar "SD Card blank or has unsupported file system" then I was required to format my SD card... however I couldn't format it using the phone and my laptop couldn't recognize it as well. Then I formatted the card using my Nokia 5800, and it works.

I tried to recover lost images and songs using Photorec. However, I was only able to recover 3 files and all of them are SQLite files. One of them is 2GB in size which match the size of all the photos and songs that I used to have.

So, is the SQLite file is my lost data or not? If it is, how can I convert it back to photos and songs that I mentioned earlier ...

I am not good with these kind of things.

Answer (score 2):

The SQLite file you recovered is a database file, you can try opening it with [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/), I can't garantee that you'll find your songs and pictures inside but it's a start. (Or post screenshot of the program with the file open in it.)